# How to rename a folder on flash drive using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a batch file that will back up the contents of a folder onto my flash drive and rename the previous folder on the flash drive. Here is the code.

```
@echo off
echo Are you sure you want to erase the previous backup file? (Y,N)
set /p ans=
if %ans%==Y goto Backup 
goto Exit
:Backup
rd "E:\Batch\BFiles Backup" /s
ren "E:\Batch\BFiles" "BFiles Backup"
:Copy
mkdir E:\Batch\BFiles
xcopy C:\Users\Habib\Documents\BFiles /E /Y E:\Batch\BFiles
echo Files have successfully been copied!
pause
:Exit
exit
```

When I run the batch file, it copies the files but doesn't rename the already existing folder because "Access is denied". I have tried running it in the administrator version of Cmd, but it still didn't work. My user is an administrator also, so i don't know why access has been denied.

Comment: Please format your code and put it in a code block.

Comment: What if you use `move` instead of `ren`? btw, it is likely due to the files being in use that you get the Access Denied message.

Comment: Where is the batch file stored?

Comment: `ren "E:\Batch\BFiles" "BFiles Backup"` should be `ren "E:\Batch\BFiles" "E:\Batch\BFiles Backup"`?

Comment: It worked fine with `ren "E:\Batch\BFiles" "BFiles Backup"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, remove your @ECHO OFF until you are done debugging your code..

Add PAUSE statements so you can stop and see what is going on..

Let's re-format your code a bit..

```
ECHO Are you sure you want to erase the previous backup file? (Y,N)
set /p ans=
if %ans%==Y goto Backup 
PAUSE
goto Exit
:Backup
PAUSE
IF EXIST "E:\Batch\BFiles Backup\." rd "E:\Batch\BFiles Backup" /s
PAUSE
IF NOT EXIST "E:\Batch\BFiles Backup\." ren "E:\Batch\BFiles" "BFiles Backup"
PAUSE
:Copy
IF NOT EXIST "E:\Batch\BFiles\." mkdir E:\Batch\BFiles
PAUSE
xcopy C:\Users\Habib\Documents\BFiles /E /Y E:\Batch\BFiles
IF errorlevel 0 echo Files have successfully been copied!
pause
:Exit
exit
```

Then, when things start looking correct, remove the PAUSE statements one by one...

Hope this helps!